# When I ran docker-compose up -d error services must be a mapping windows indentation error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I follow the tutorial in [here](https://binus.ac.id/knowledge/2020/12/membuat-php-dev-environment-dengan-docker/) . When I'm in docker-compose.yml, I can't make the correct file, because the indentation not true. This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
# Version
version: '3.1'

# Setup
services:
# PHP
php:
depends_on:
- db
image: docker-php-dev
restart: always
ports:
- 5000:80
volumes:
- ./development:/var/www/html

# PHPMyAdmin
phpmyadmin:
depends_on:
- db
image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
restart: always
ports:
- 5050:80
environment:
PMA_HOST: db

# MySQL
db:
image: mysql:5.7
restart: always
volumes:
- wordpress_db:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

# Volumes
volumes:
wordpress_db:
wordpress_uploads:
```

I always get error when I run docker-compose up -d. Can someone tell me how to make correct docker-compose.yml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing to a bad document which loss all `indent`, you should reference to [compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) to see how a good compose file should look.

In basic, after write a compose file, you should use `docker-compose config` to check if the format is ok or not.

For your scenario, the workable fix is next, FYI:

```
# Version
version: '3.1'

# Setup
services:
    # PHP
    php:
        depends_on:
        - db
        image: docker-php-dev
        restart: always
        ports:
        - 5000:80
        volumes:
        - ./development:/var/www/html

    # PHPMyAdmin
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
        - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
        - 5050:80
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: db

    # MySQL
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        volumes:
        - wordpress_db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

# Volumes
volumes:
    wordpress_db:
    wordpress_uploads:
```